# Ms Access ListBox, Value not updated to the selected Item when set by vba code

Tags: ms-access

If the user click do an entry in a ListBox (single select) the entry is selected and the default member `Value` is updated to the bound column of the selected entry.

```
Debug.Print lstBox.Value '-> Bound value of the new selected Entry
```

But when I change the selected entry by vba code then `Value` is not updated.

```
...
.Selected(.ItemsSelected(0)) = False
.Selected(newPos) = True
....

Debug.Print lstBox.Value '-> Bound value of the before selected Entry
```

Why that and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After setting row selection:

`Me.lstBox = Me.lstBox.Column(0)`

or inside With block

`.Value = .Column(0)`